# nodejs - Hanlde a cpu intensive route

Tags: node.js, express

I am writing a express js app.There is one route when hit makes a schedule and give the generated schedule to the user as response. Its a little cpu intensive task. So as far i know running a cpu intensive task on the main thread will make the app unresponsive. Is there a pacakge or a way which can be used to run this task on another thread an respond back to the user who hit that route.

Comment: Yes, you will want to use the [`Worker` class](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_class_worker) from the `cluster` module. It is not difficult, but not trivial. If you search on node workers though, you should find some decent tutorial code.

Comment: I tried a module called `tiny-worker`. I want to start the worker when a specific routes gets hit. I am able to do that. But how do i give response when the worker finished the job back to the user who hit the route?

Comment: Yes, that's kind of of weak doc isn't it? Consider checking out the rather more broadly used [node-webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) which provides some examples in its readme, including one with supporting a http route. In my personal case, I simply wrote a little module to wrap and sugar the native node Worker class because I wanted a promise-returning interface. It is quite late for me here presently, but if you are still having issues with this tomorrow, I can probably find some time to bang it togehter into a gist for you.

Comment: Thanks Barry. That would be helpful for me

Comment: Sounds good. I'll do it in the AM.

Comment: My day didn't out as I expected. A bit of delay. Please see [this repo](https://github.com/barry-johnson/express-worker-example)

Comment: Thanks a lot... I will check it out when I get back from College

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `worker-farm` library to make it easier to fork a process to perform task out of the main thread. (This is what `jest` uses)
https://github.com/rvagg/node-worker-farm